# Pandas: How to draw bar graph on month over counts

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe `df` as below:

```
Student_id   Date_of_visit(d/m/y)
1            1/4/2020
1            30/12/2019
1            26/12/2019
2            3/1/2021
2            10/1/2021
3            4/5/2020
3            22/8/2020
```

How can I get the bar-graph with `x-axis` as month-year(eg: y-ticks:  Dec 2019,  Jan 2020, Feb 2020) and on `y-axis` - the total number of students (count) visited on a particular month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert values to datetimes, then use [`DataFrame.resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`Resampler.size`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.size.html) for counts, create new format of datetimes by [`DatetimeIndex.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html):

```
df['Date_of_visit'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date_of_visit'], dayfirst=True)

s = df.resample('M', on='Date_of_visit')['Student_id'].size()

s.index = s.index.strftime('%b %Y')

print (s)
Date_of_visit
Dec 2019    2
Jan 2020    0
Feb 2020    0
Mar 2020    0
Apr 2020    1
May 2020    1
Jun 2020    0
Jul 2020    0
Aug 2020    1
Sep 2020    0
Oct 2020    0
Nov 2020    0
Dec 2020    0
Jan 2021    2
Name: Student_id, dtype: int64
```

If need count only unique `Student_id` use [`Resampler.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.resample.Resampler.nunique.html):

```
s = df.resample('M', on='Date_of_visit')['Student_id'].nunique()

s.index = s.index.strftime('%b %Y')

print (s)
Date_of_visit
Dec 2019    1
Jan 2020    0
Feb 2020    0
Mar 2020    0
Apr 2020    1
May 2020    1
Jun 2020    0
Jul 2020    0
Aug 2020    1
Sep 2020    0
Oct 2020    0
Nov 2020    0
Dec 2020    0
Jan 2021    1
Name: Student_id, dtype: int64
```

Last plot by [`Series.plot.bar`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html)

```
s.plot.bar()
```